# Unable to insert into database using JPA. Tried merge, persist and INSERT query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to add an entry into AttributeName:

```
@Entity
public class AttributeName implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "attNameId", nullable = false)
    private Long attNameId;

    @Column(name = "attName", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String attName;

    @Column(name = "required", nullable = false)
    private boolean required;

    ...

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class AttributeNameManagerBean implements AttributeNameManagerRemote
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "mainPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public AttributeNameManagerBean()
    {

    }

    ...
```

I first must add this entry and use the newly created id to insert into the Attribute which stores this id (to link to an AttributeValue).

I have tried:

- `AttributeName savedAttName = entityManager.merge(newAttName);`
- `entityManager.persist(newAttName); entityManager.flush();`
- `entityManager.create(Native)Query("INSERT...");`

I receive a `ConstraintViolationException` later but the main problem is that the insert statement in any of the 3 above forms does not throw an exception, but when I query the database the new entry is not there.
In the first example, `savedAttName` contains the newly generated unqiue PK :S

Note: I am sure that `attName` is a new unique entry into the database.]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Happy to provide any more information if required.

**Edit**: There is an attNameId field in Attribute. Attribute has two unique constraints:

`uniqueConstraints={
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"attNameId", "attValueId"} ),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"sectionId", "sectionIndex"} )}`

The sectionId and sectionIndex being entered are a unique combination which doesn't exist currently in AttributeName (which only has 1 entry, which I manually inserted).

**Fix:**
Removed the constraints from the table, reployed. Then dropped the table, re-added the constraints and it works. I'm guessing it didn't correctly set up the constraints.

Comment: did you commit the transaction ?

Comment: I haven't been using `getTransation().begin()` and `getTransation().commit()` anywhere in my system. The rest has worked fine without it. Do you think it is necessary in this case:?

Comment: Hibernate requires transactions for persistence operations (as does the JPA spec). Other JPA implementations may handle non-transactional operations fine (vendor extension).

Comment: I am using a JTA entityManager

Comment: Using `entityManager.persist` is the right choice. Are you inside JEE container? How do you initialize entity manager (container managed / application-managed)? Does `AttributeName` entity has relationships to  other entities? Try to avoid `ConstraintViolationException` first.

Comment: Ok I'll use persist. I have updated my question to hopefully answer your question.

Comment: @wypieprz I believe the constraint violation has something to do with trying to add a FK value into Attribute when the matching PK value doesn't exist in AttributeName

Comment: So it's _transaction-scoped container-managed_ entity manager, thus `entityManager.persist` is enough as begin & commit/rollback is done automatically within a given method. Are you able to commit / query without specifying unique constraint?

Comment: @wypieprz I can commit / query fine with other tables (entities) which have fewer constraints

Comment: Does it solve the problem? If it does the root-cause was related to unique constraint, doesn't it?

Comment: @wypieprz i have tried manually inserting the exact same data with no issue.

Comment: @wypieprz As I am using JTA should I being using some sort of explicit transaction call?

Comment: With JTA and `@Stateless` container you don't need explicit transaction calls (begin/commit/rollback).